# Where not in from two table Eloquent Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have table: User, Certification, Waybill and user_certification and waybill_certification.

I want create query using Eloquent where i check that user have certification which checked in waybill

```
$check = \App\User::with('certification', 'waybill.certification')->
```

And i dont now what now, is is possible?

I have create relationship in models

Waybill

```
  public function certification() {
    return $this -> hasMany('App\WaybillCertification');
  }

  public function user() {
    return $this -> belongsTo('App\User');
  }
```

User

```
public function waybill() {
  return $this -> hasMany('App\Waybill');
}

public function certification() {
  return $this -> hasMany('App\UserCertification');
}
```

I know i could use query builder for it but i would like learn how do it with eloquent.

Recently i used mysqli_query
Code:

```
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT c.ID
    FROM request_certification rc
    INNER JOIN certifications c
    ON rc.ID_certification = c.ID
    WHERE rc.ID_request = '$requestID'
    AND rc.ID_certification NOT IN (
      SELECT c.ID
      FROM certifications c
      INNER JOIN user_certification uc ON uc.certification_id = c.ID
      WHERE user_ID = $userID)");

  if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Thanks for help you.

Comment: Are you asking about `User::find(1)->waybill->isEmpty()` ?

Comment: No, i check it in Waybill Model as Atribute and is information for administrator. I want check User certification and Waybill which user send.

Comment: how do you check the certification? is it a boolean or? i know how to do the relationel queries, but don't understand what you mean with: "that user have certification which checked in waybill" would where('certification', 1); be enough?

Comment: This explains it all: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence
Unless you can give more information as to why that does not work for you

Comment: Every user have certification and every waybill have the same, i want check that user who send waybill and marked for example (fragile cargo). In my system user need to buy certification and where he marked certification which he doesn't have i want display message for administrator.

Comment: Someone can help me?